# Sharing Window XP and Windows 10 Computers

Tags: windows-xp, windows-10, network-shares

Before I installed windows 10 to one windows 8.1 and two windows 7 computers, my windows XP PC was able to share both ways on my network.

When windows 10 was installed to the aforementioned PC's, the xp pc does not share either way with the Windows 10 computers.

ALL computers DO HAVE access to the internet without problems.

Any suggestions on how to remedy this problem?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Can you clarify "*xp pc does not share either way*"? Does this cause an error message? Can the computers see each  other on the network? Does Windows 10 see your network as private or public?

Comment: My XP PC does not see other computers on the network, nor do the windows 10 pc see the xp pc on the network.  All three Windows 10 PC see each other and share without a problem and show as private.  I did not mention that I also have a personal WDCloud drive on the network which shares with the windows 10 computers but DOES NOT share to the XP computer.  Thanks for you interest and help

Comment: Take a look at this article - [Sharing files on Windows 10 to Windows XP](http://www.tenforums.com/network-sharing/2129-sharing-files-windows-10-windows-xp.html). Since XP is no longer supported, MS doesn't appear to be concerned with it.